# Docker container not showing volume mounted - Access issue

Tags: linux, docker, selinux

```
root@centdev01$ grep -e CMD -e RUN Dockerfile
RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get -y install ruby ruby-dev build-essential redis-tools
RUN gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri sinatra json redis
RUN mkdir -p /opt/webapp
RUN chmod 777 /opt/webapp
CMD ["/opt/webapp/bin/webapp"]

root@centdev01$ docker build -t "alok87/sinatra" .

root@centdev01$ docker run -d -p 80 --name ubunsin10 -v $PWD/webapp:/opt/webapp alok87/sinatra
25ekgjalgjal25rkg
root@centdev01$ docker logs ubunsin10
/opt/webapp/bin/webapp: Permission Denied - /opt/webapp/bin/webapp ( Errno:EACCESS)
```

The issue is the volume is being mounted to the container but from the container it is not having any acces to the mounted volume. I can cd to /opt/webapp/bin but i can not ls /opt/webapp/bin.

Please suggest how it can be fixed. The host mount has all files having 777 permission.

Comment: Why did you cut out a lot of your `Dockerfile`? It is hard to see if you're doing anything you shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

Docker processes have the *svirt_lxc_net_t* default type. By default these processes are **not** allowed to access your content in */var*, */root* and */home*.

You have specify a suitable type label for your host folder, to allow the container processes to access the content. You can do this by giving the $PWD/webapp folder the type label *svirt_sandbox_file_t*.

```
chcon -Rt svirt_sandbox_file_t $PWD/webapp
```

After this, you can access the folder from within the container. Read more about it in [Dan Walsh's article - Bringing new security features to Docker](https://opensource.com/business/14/9/security-for-docker)

Comment: Thanks Dan. the problem is resolved after starting the container with the --privileged=true flag.

Comment: This fixes your problem at hand, but if you run privileged, you are basically giving your docker container full rights to your host system. Think about security, this is probably not what you want to expose to the public.